# Thread syncing animations in iOS across functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, animation

I'm writing an iOS app in Objective C. In one my classes (a View Controller), I have 2 different functions. Each of these functions, within it, has a call to an animation (UIView animateWithDuration). Let's call these functions Function A and Function B, and the animations they call within themselves Animation A and Animation B respectively. Animation A is sort of long and delayed, while B is pretty quick.

I absolutely need the animation in Function B to only start running once the animation in Function A completes. i.e. Animation B has to run after Animation A completes.

I CANNOT call Animation B from Animation A's completion block, because Animation B needs parameters available only to Function B in order to run:

```
FunctionA()
{
    AnimationA()
}

Function B(x, y, z)
{
    AnimationB(x, y, z)
}
```

How on earth do I solve this problem? I've tried creating a new separate queue and then stacking the Animation A and B calls on that, but it still doesn't work. What inevitably seems to happen is that, I'm guessing the actual UIView animateWithDuration call will invariably spawn its own thread, and so the block of code that runs it that I place on the queue will return as completed even while it's still going on, because it's the completion handler that is anyways going to run when it's done (which I can't use for the reason mentioned previously).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you call function B from the completion block?

Comment: Function B contains a bunch of parameters that aren't available to Function A, that are needed for the animation. I don't want to have to pass all those parameters to Function A just for the purposes of being able to call Function B from its completion block.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. You pass the parameters directly to your call of function B, they don't have to go through function A. I think you need to show how you're calling these two functions so I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: If I call Function B from the completion block, where am I going to get the arguments I need to pass to it? Because the call to Function B is now in the completion block - which is inside Function A - those parameters have to be within Function A, right?

Comment: Edited my main question text to show how i'm calling the functions.